# JavaScript error in IE only, works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, wordpress

I have a very basic slider on my homepage, but for some reason it stopped working in IE7, 8 and 9. I have no problems in all other browsers tested.

Here is a link to the JavaScript file I am using:

http://pastebin.com/xw3MpvCA

The relevent code for this slider is on the top of the file.

the website in question:
http://shawn.theanointedone.com

The slider in question is the small one with the black background right beneath my primary slider. It simply scrolls through a number of photo's that take a user to a specified Wordpress slideshow post.

Keep in mind that I am brand new to JavaScript, and doing my absolute best to get it right. I did run the script through jsLint, and it seems to come back fine.

Is there a rather basic rule that I have broken somewhere that only applies to IE?

Thanks so much for everyone's help. I'm actually having a great time and loving JavaScript the more I learn about it.

Comment: You can see errors in Javascript, with line numbers to help, if you toggle "Internet Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Display a notification about every script error".  Alternately, there's a little yellow warning icon in the lower left that pops up with a script error.  Click it and you can turn on error reporting also.  This could help you pinpoint the line in this code and for future projects.

Comment: Try wrapping the calling code inside a $(document).ready() function?

Comment: What's the ID of the broken slider?

Comment: Not entirely related to your problem here, but the code can be shortened by a considerable amount. You're repeating yourself a huge number of time there.

Comment: Is posting code only in jsfiddle/whatever now acceptable? I would say not.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered what the issue is. Its with the disableCustomButtons(carousel) function in scripts.js from line 25 to line 40. What happens is that when the document loads the visible arrow on the left has an id of #mycarousel-next with a disabled attribute set to false while the invisible arrow on the right with id of #mycarousel-prev has 'disabled' set to true.

In IE both arrows have disabled set to 'false', which should not be so, that is why you are experiencing this problem and its from the disableCustomButtons function from line 25 to 40:

Thank you everyone for the advice!

The only thing I was unsure of is 'Yi Jiang' mentioned that my code could be shortened a lot, but gave no examples of how to do so.

Any ideas on this?